# Why instanceVariableNames is a String and not a more structured collection

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm a Smalltalk beginner, currently playing with Pharo and I'm curious about a choice in the subclass message: the keyword instanceVariableNames wants something able to answer to the subStrings message. I wonder why it doesn't expect something more structured like an array, since what is needed is a collection of symbols.

```
Object subclass: #Experiment instanceVariableNames: #(#foo #bar).
```

My only guessing at this is some historical reason: maybe not all Smalltalks have arrays or their syntax differs to much to slip into an inner message as subclass. Is there any other explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Pharo vision document, one of the points is to change that and have a real notion of instance variables.  Check these links if you are interested:

- http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Verw11bFlexibleObjectLayouts.pdf
- http://www.pharo-project.org/download/pictures/be/j32hajf3kjdbsebqo0a9zc5tk8ekxt/pharovision.pdf

Comment: Thank you, very interesting references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's a bit strange. I think that that main reason is that it needs names, so upon class creation compiler parses string and gets names as substrings, Also you don't need to check if someone has passed you an array with numbers or another arrays.

As for array itself, it was present in Smalltalk-80 specification, so they are quite common. (not as dynamic arrays `{ expr1 . expr2 . expr3}` that were introduced in Squeak.

Also there are a lot of strange things. For example right now Pharo uses *Parser* that is a subclass of *Scanner*… Thou that is going to change soon.

Comment: Indeed, the new ClassBuilder will accept real Arrays for the instance variable names.